# How to implement Flux / Redux Action authorization or availability

Tags: javascript, rest, redux, flux, hateoas

### The Requirement

We are currently building a client App that is supposed to work with a HATEOAS REST-API. This means the API itself tells us which further actions are currently available - comparable with an authorization.

For example:
We have an entity `Projects` and a Component `ProjectWidget` which is basically a paginated List of Projects. The Server API gives us the first 10 Projects by default and - depending if there are more - integrates an URL to the next 10 Projects. The JSON-Reponse for a Page 2 of such a list would look like this:

```
{
   "_embedded" : [ ... ], // list of project-entities
   "_links" : {
      "prev" : "myApi.com/projects?page=1"
      "self" : "myApi.com/projects?page=2"
      "next" : "myApi.com/projects?page=3"
   }
}
```

On page 1, the `links` section is simply missing the `prev` property as there is no previous page. In my component, I want to show a `Previous` and `Next` Button depending if those properties are available in the response or not.

**Conclusion**: My App doesnt know which actions are available and when they are. This means that the currently available actions also belong to the state of the current app as well as the data itself.

### Build it with Flux/Redux

Now I want to somehow put this into a flux architecture using for example redux (the concrete implementation doesnt really matter at this point).

Of course, the asynchronous calls to my server-api need to go into an **ActionCreator** which then has two tasks when the server responds:

1. Dispatch Action to put the data itself into the store
2. Dispatch Action to put the next available actions (or at least the information on how to create them) into the store

The model could look like this:

```
{
  projects: {
     data: [...], // the list of my projects
     actions: {
        previous: 'myApi.com/projects?page=1' // Prepared action to load the previous 10 
        next: 'myApi.com/projects?page=3' // Prepared action to load the next 10 Projects
     }
  }
}
```

Then the **ActionCreator** would need to look like this:

```
export loadProjectsFrom(href){
   return () => {
      myApi
      .get(href)
      .subscribe((response) => {
          store.dispatch({type: 'LOADED_PROJECTS', payload: response._embedded})
          store.dispatch({
             type: 'LOADED_PROJECTS_ACTIONS', 
             payload: {next: response._links.next, prev: reponse._links.prev})
      });
   } 
}
```

A ViewComponent could then easily subscribe to both - the actions and the projects and create new actions from the information provieded in the store:

```
let state = store.getState();
if(state.projects.actions.next){
   // Render the button with onclick event calling the function below
}

onClick() {
    let href = store.getState().projects.actions.next;
    let loadAction = actionCreator.loadProjectsFrom(href);
    store.dispatch(loadAction);
}
```

### My Questions

1. Is my conclusion even correct that the available actions are part of the state?
2. Is it a good pattern to create actions from information directly taken from the store? (it seems like it introduces a tight coupling between the two)
3. Are there any alternatives on how to implement this sort of *Actionauthorization* or *-availability*?